# How to keep a dynamic table row when it has no value?

Tags: html, reactjs, html-table, datatable

I have this code :

```
const HistoricalGrid = ((props) => {
return (
    <div className="main-table">
        <DataTable rows={props.selectedFile} headers={headers}>
            {({ rows, headers, getTableProps, getHeaderProps, getRowProps }) => (
                <Table {...getTableProps()}>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            {headers.map((header) => (
                                <TableHeader {...getHeaderProps({ header })}>
                                    {header.header}
                                </TableHeader>
                            ))}
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {props.selectedFile.map((row) => (
                            <TableRow rows="4"  {...getRowProps({ row })}>
                                <TableCell key={row.id} >{row.name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell key={row.id}>{row.type}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell key={row.id}>{new Date().toString()}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            )}
        </DataTable>
```

But, I only get the rows data when a button is clicked, how can I keep the rows even if has no value ?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the array length and use a ternary :

```js
                        {props.selectedFile.length                                                                       
                            ? props.selectedFile.map((row) => (
                               ...
                            ))
                            : <TableRow>No result</TableRow>
                        }
```

Comment: how can I do that with 4 rows? because if I use 4 row in the else... when I get data it will be one row in the true condition, you know ?

Comment: I haven't enough informations to help you clearly I think. For example, what do your TableRow component do ?
What you do looks really strange without TableRow props context.
Because TableRow probably render a <tr> no ? which contains 3 <td/>.
So the rows="4" is for what ? You render 4 times <tr>{props.children}</tr> by array index ?.
Anyway, if you want to set 4 tr in the else you can do : 
`: <>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
</>
`

Comment: yeah, almost... I want to set 4 initial empty rows, but when I receive the data, the 4 rows will turn into one according to my code... how can I fill the 4 rows naturally ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const generateNRows = nb => {
     const rows = [];
     for($i = 0; $i < $nb; $i++){
         rows.push(<tr/>);
     }
     return rows;
}

const nowDate = new Date();

return (...

                        {props.selectedFile.map((row) => (
                            <TableRow  {...row} key={row.id} >
                                <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{row.type}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{nowDate.toString()}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))}
                        {props.selectedFile.length < 4 && (
                            <>
                                {generateNRows(4 - props.selectedFile.length)}
                            </>
                         )}
```